# Can I insert an element to a given iterator for a map?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `std::map`. I find a lower bound of a key and make sure the key is not used in the map. And can I insert a element to a given iterator for a map? If so how?

```
map<int, double> m;
int key = 1;
auto itr = m.lower_bound(key);
if (itr == m.end() || itr->first != key)
    m.insert(itr, make_pair(key, 3.14)); // how is the performance? Any better way?
```

Comment: Does it work? If so, great. If not, tell us in what way it does not work. As for "how is the performance?", find out by measuring it against your alternatives. We cannot predict how your code, build configuration, compiler, OS, platform, architecture, computer will behave.

Comment: What's wrong with just using insert? It already checks if the key exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The associative container requirements say about `emplace_hint` and related operations that the complexity is "logarithmic in general, but amortized constant if the element is inserted right before `p`" (where `p` is the hint iterator).

So if you only use correct hints, then the complexity is amortized-constant, independent of the size of the map. (Of course you still have the cost of performing the initial look-up.)

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the "hint" version of `insert()` is that the map could the passed iterator as an indication of where the object may go. There is a guarantee that the performance is "amortized constant if t is inserted right before p." (where `p` is the hint iterator).

In cases where the value is reasonably cheap to construct, it may be advisable to use `m.insert(std::make_pair(key, 3.14))` directly: the element remains unchanged if the `insert()` fails. The function returns a `std::pair<iterator, bool>` with the `first` element pointing at the newly inserted element and the `second` element indicating if the node was inserted.

Comment: If the key doesn't exist in the map, `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` are equivalent.

Comment: @T.C.: true - I didn't think that one through properly. I shall remove the corresponding part of the answer... Thanks.